# Custom middleware to redirect user based on a role based on certain checks

Tags: frappe

I am trying to customize my frappe app based on a role.

1. user with `Role Website` logs in.
2. Check if the user has company set
3. If it is not set then redirect them to a custom page where they can select company.

If the user tries to navigate away to any other URL then redirect them to `Step 2`.
I believe it can be done with a middleware. But, my question is, where would we invoke the middleware in my custom app?

I tried to to add a custom middleware and tried to invoke in the `frappe` app but I dont think this is the suggested way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add an auth or login hook to do this for you. Check the user data, set the route location in the flags and raise `frappe.Redirect`

Refs:

- [Auth Hooks](https://frappeframework.com/docs/v13/user/en/python-api/hooks#auth-hooks)
- [Session Hooks](https://frappeframework.com/docs/v13/user/en/python-api/hooks#session-hooks)
- Searches in the Frappe Source Code (keywords: redirect, redirect_location)